# Mod operator in Java

Tags: java, operators, modulus

```
public class Triangle {     
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n=12345, x=15;
        int res =(n % x);
        System.out.println(res);
    }
}
```

The statement `int res = (n%x)` is `0`. Why?

Comment: Hint : `12345 = 823*15+0`

Comment: 1) Please don't forget to add a '?' to questions!  Some people do a search in the page for '?' and if none exists in the 'question' go directly to the next (actual) question in line.  2) Please use code formatting for code, input/output & structured documents like HTML or XML.  To do that, select the sample and click the `{}` button above the messaged posting/editing form.

Comment: what exactly is your question ?... you are getting the right answer (0)..

Answer (score 4):

When you do,

```
12345/15
```

It exactly divides it by 823 times and reminder is zero.

There is nothing wrong it with %. Make sure that you want reminder or the result of `n/x`